# Facebook test users flooding my NEWLY CREATED application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have just created a new application on Facebook and I haven't shared the newly created app link with anyone but suddenly a lot of Facebook test users started to flood my app. All of them are from Ireland. Does anyone have any ideas why they are coming to my app?

Answer (score 0):

File a bug since only a developer of your app can create test users.